# Importing csv file with node.js and postgresql

Tags: node.js

Im importing a large number of records from a csv file. but Im getting an error that looks like I'm running out of memory.

> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Below you will see my code.

```
//date,date_block_num,shop_id,item_id,item_price,item_cnt_day
const company = 'COURSERA';
const csvFilePath = '/home/atlantageek/product_data/salesdata/sales_train.csv';
const { Client } = require('pg');

const csv = require("csvtojson");
const client = new Client({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    user: 'me',
    password: 'secretpassword',
    database: 'cooldb'
})
client.connect();


csv().fromFile(csvFilePath)
    .subscribe((json) => {
        //console.log(json);
        var dt = json.date.split('.');
        client.query("INSERT into series(orgName,  cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4,cat5,dt, val, attr1)" + 
                                " values($1::text, $2,   $3,   $4,   $5,  $6,  $7, $8,   $9)",
            [company, json.shop_id, json.item_id,'','','', dt[2] + '-' + dt[1] + '-' + dt[0], json.item_cnt_day, json.item_price]).then((result) => {
                console.log("-------------------");

            }).catch(e => {
                console.error(e.stack);
            })
    }, onError, onComplete)

function onError(err) { console.log(err) }
function onComplete(err) { console.log(err) }
```

I know the code is not efficient and I can do bulk inserts but outside of that I think I am running out of memory because I have so many inserts in flight.  With node's built in Asynchronous nature how do I slow down inserts so I dont have so many transactions being run simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be more complex than which you think. If you just want to read data from csv file and insert into PG. You can delay the insert operation using `setTimeout`. This may enlarge the total time it should originally take, but it really works. If you want to build a seriously system which can hold high concurrency. I suggest using redis and message queue. Using some library helps you.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/smrchy/rsmq)